# Too many redirects while web scraping a collage website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape data about course IDs and times of classes from a college course-schedule website (https://internet3.trincoll.edu/ptools/courselisting.aspx).The website has dropdown menu making you select your major and shows you classes corresponding to the major you select. The dropdown menu content uses the and tag.

This is the code I wrote (and it was working until a couple weeks ago)-

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://internet3.trincoll.edu/ptools/courselisting.aspx"

with requests.session() as s:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url).content, "html.parser")
    courses = [v["value"] for v in soup.select("#ddlList [value]")]

    for c in courses:
        data = {}
        for inp in soup.select("input[value][name]"):
            data[inp["name"]] = inp["value"]

        data["ddlList"] = c
        data["ddlLevelList"] = "0"
        data["ddlTermList"] = "1241"  # <-- Fall 2023
        data["ddlSession"] = "0"
        data["__EVENTTARGET"] = "ddlList"
        data["__EVENTARGUMENT"] = ""
        data["__LASTFOCUS"] = ""

        soup = BeautifulSoup(s.post(url, data=data).content, "html.parser")

        print(c)
        print("-" * 80)
        for id_, time, title, c_id in zip(soup.select(".TITLE_id"), soup.select(".TITLE_times"), soup.select(".TITLE_title"), soup.find_all('td', nowrap="true")):
            print(f"{id_.text:<10} {title.text} {time.text} {c_id.text}")
        print()
```

**Now, this gives me a "requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects." error. What should I do in this case?**

I've read some similar threads and it seems like it might be because my request gets in a loop (hence a lot of redirects), but I am new to beautifulsoup (and web scraping in general) and do not understand the steps I need to take to fix that.

Full Error-

```
ANTH
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1701       Intro to Cultural Anthropology TR: 1:30PM-2:45PM ANTH-101-01
1797       Intro to Cultural Anthropology TR: 9:25AM-10:40AM ANTH-101-02
2398       Intro to Cultural Anthropology MW: 1:30PM-2:45PM ANTH-101-03
2360       Intro to Political Ecology TR: 2:55PM-4:10PM ANTH-227-01
2435       Women in the Caribbean T: 6:30PM-9:00PM ANTH-241-01
2643       Political Violence in SE Asia TR: 10:50AM-12:05PM ANTH-261-01
3029       Anthropology of Museums TR: 2:55PM-4:10PM ANTH-271-01
3136       Anthropology of Religion TR: 1:30PM-2:45PM ANTH-281-01
2375       Ethnographic Methods & Writing M: 1:30PM-4:10PM ANTH-301-01
1415       History of Anth Thought W: 1:30PM-4:10PM ANTH-302-01
3486       Cultural Neuroscience MW: 10:00AM-11:15AM ANTH-309-01
3148       Magic, Sorcery & Witchcraft MW: 11:30AM-12:45PM ANTH-317-01
3030       Anthropology of Food MW: 2:55PM-4:10PM ANTH-330-01
3295       Global Indigeneity MW: 11:30AM-12:45PM ANTH-353-01
1785       Independent Study TBA ANTH-399-01
1718       Teaching Assistantship TBA ANTH-466-01
2982       Research Assistantship TBA ANTH-490-01
3362       Senior Thesis TBA ANTH-497-01
3363       Senior Thesis Part 1 TBA ANTH-498-01
3011       Anthropology & Education MW: 10:00AM-11:15AM EDUC-320-01
3278       Buddhist Materiality MW: 11:30AM-12:45PM RELG-321-01

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/anupamkhargharia/Desktop/Computer Science/trincoll_scheduler/course_web_scraper/main.py", line 23, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.post(url, data=data).content, "html.parser")
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 637, in post
    return self.request("POST", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 725, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen]
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 725, in <listcomp>
    history = [resp for resp in gen]
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 191, in resolve_redirects
    raise TooManyRedirects(
requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to correctly mimic the `POST` request and since it's a `.NET` app on the backend you need to validate it with `__EVENTVALIDATION` and `__VIEWSTATE`.

Get all the course names and while you're looping over them, you build your query payload. I've used:

- <COURSE_NAME>
- all levels
- Fall 2023

The code:

```py
import time

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tabulate import tabulate

url = "https://internet3.trincoll.edu/ptools/courselisting.aspx"


def wait_a_bit(wait_for: int = 5) -> None:
    time.sleep(wait_for)


with requests.session() as session:
    course_selection = (
        BeautifulSoup(session.get(url).text, "html.parser")
        .select("#ddlList [value]")
    )
    all_courses = [[c.get("value"), c.getText()] for c in course_selection]

    for course in all_courses:
        course_id, course_name = course
        print(f"Getting {course_name}...")

        v_state = (
            BeautifulSoup(session.get(url).text, "html.parser")
            .find("input", {"name": "__VIEWSTATE"})["value"]
        )
        event_validation = (
            BeautifulSoup(session.get(url).text, "html.parser")
            .find("input", {"name": "__EVENTVALIDATION"})["value"]
        )

        payload = {
            "__EVENTVALIDATION": event_validation,
            "__VIEWSTATE": v_state,
            "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR": "3786FA90",
            "rblLstType": 1,
            "ddlList": course_id,
            "ddlLevelList": 0,
            "ddlTermList": 1241,
            "ddlSession": 0,
            "btnSubmit": "Submit",
        }

        response = session.post(url, data=payload)
        courses = (
            BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
            .select_one('table[class="TITLE_tbl"]')
        )

        table_rows = zip(
            courses.select(".TITLE_id"),
            courses.select(".TITLE_times"),
            courses.select(".TITLE_title"),
            courses.find_all('td', nowrap="true"),
        )

        my_table = [
            [
                id_.getText(),
                time.getText(),
                title.getText(),
                c_id.getText(),
            ] for id_, time, title, c_id in table_rows
        ]

        df = pd.DataFrame(my_table, columns=["ID", "Time", "Title", "Course ID"])
        df.to_csv(f"{course_id}_{course_name}.csv", index=False)
        print(tabulate(df, headers="keys", tablefmt="psql", showindex=False))

        wait_a_bit(wait_for=3)
```

You should see something like this:

```
Getting American Studies...
+------+---------------------+--------------------------------+-------------+
|   ID | Time                | Title                          | Course ID   |
|------+---------------------+--------------------------------+-------------|
| 3170 | MW: 1:30PM-2:45PM   | African-American History       | AMST-209-01 |
| 3191 | TR: 2:55PM-4:10PM   | Anthropology of Museums        | AMST-271-01 |
| 3252 | MW: 2:55PM-4:10PM   | Born in Blood                  | AMST-285-01 |
| 3182 | TR: 9:25AM-10:40AM  | Early American Women's Lit     | AMST-307-01 |
| 3172 | TR: 10:50AM-12:05PM | Abolition: A Global History    | AMST-315-01 |
| 3174 | MW: 10:00AM-11:15AM | Sports and American Society    | AMST-340-01 |
| 2355 | TR: 10:50AM-12:05PM | Race and Urban Space           | AMST-357-01 |
| 1416 | TBA                 | Independent Study              | AMST-399-01 |
| 3175 | R: 6:30PM-9:00PM    | Race, Gender, Global Security  | AMST-409-01 |
| 3080 | T: 6:30PM-9:00PM    | Black Women Writers            | AMST-445-01 |
| 1449 | TBA                 | Teaching Assistantship         | AMST-466-01 |
| 1542 | TBA                 | Research Assistantship         | AMST-490-01 |
| 3359 | TBA                 | Senior Thesis Part 1           | AMST-498-01 |
| 2745 | W: 6:30PM-9:00PM    | Approaches to American Studies | AMST-801-01 |
| 3177 | R: 6:30PM-9:00PM    | Race, Gender, Global Security  | AMST-809-01 |
| 3079 | T: 6:30PM-9:00PM    | Black Women Writers            | AMST-845-01 |
| 1565 | TBA                 | Museums and Communities Intern | AMST-894-01 |
| 1441 | TBA                 | Independent Study              | AMST-940-01 |
| 1437 | TBA                 | Research Project               | AMST-953-01 |
| 1438 | TBA                 | Thesis Part I                  | AMST-954-01 |
| 1440 | TBA                 | Thesis Part II                 | AMST-955-01 |
| 1439 | TBA                 | Thesis                         | AMST-956-01 |
+------+---------------------+--------------------------------+-------------+
Getting Anthropology...
+------+---------------------+--------------------------------+-------------+
|   ID | Time                | Title                          | Course ID   |
|------+---------------------+--------------------------------+-------------|
| 1701 | TR: 1:30PM-2:45PM   | Intro to Cultural Anthropology | ANTH-101-01 |
| 1797 | TR: 9:25AM-10:40AM  | Intro to Cultural Anthropology | ANTH-101-02 |
| 2398 | MW: 1:30PM-2:45PM   | Intro to Cultural Anthropology | ANTH-101-03 |
| 2360 | TR: 2:55PM-4:10PM   | Intro to Political Ecology     | ANTH-227-01 |
| 2435 | T: 6:30PM-9:00PM    | Women in the Caribbean         | ANTH-241-01 |
| 2643 | TR: 10:50AM-12:05PM | Political Violence in SE Asia  | ANTH-261-01 |
| 3029 | TR: 2:55PM-4:10PM   | Anthropology of Museums        | ANTH-271-01 |
| 3136 | TR: 1:30PM-2:45PM   | Anthropology of Religion       | ANTH-281-01 |
| 2375 | M: 1:30PM-4:10PM    | Ethnographic Methods & Writing | ANTH-301-01 |
| 1415 | W: 1:30PM-4:10PM    | History of Anth Thought        | ANTH-302-01 |
| 3486 | MW: 10:00AM-11:15AM | Cultural Neuroscience          | ANTH-309-01 |
| 3148 | MW: 11:30AM-12:45PM | Magic, Sorcery & Witchcraft    | ANTH-317-01 |
| 3030 | MW: 2:55PM-4:10PM   | Anthropology of Food           | ANTH-330-01 |
| 3295 | MW: 11:30AM-12:45PM | Global Indigeneity             | ANTH-353-01 |
| 1785 | TBA                 | Independent Study              | ANTH-399-01 |
| 1718 | TBA                 | Teaching Assistantship         | ANTH-466-01 |
| 2982 | TBA                 | Research Assistantship         | ANTH-490-01 |
| 3362 | TBA                 | Senior Thesis                  | ANTH-497-01 |
| 3363 | TBA                 | Senior Thesis Part 1           | ANTH-498-01 |
+------+---------------------+--------------------------------+-------------+

...
```

Bonus: each table is saved to a `.csv` file.